# MFC combobox killfocus doesn't work

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc, onkillfocus

I have a dialog box with several `combobox`es in it as a member variables. The control wizard lets me create handlers for the `combobox`es for the `CBN_KILLFOCUS` message. For example, one such handler is automatically called

```
void MyDlg::OnKillfocusMyCombo()
```

My expectation is that this handler would be called just as soon as I tab out of it. But it doesn't get called.

Comment: It works like charm here. Give us some more information.

Comment: Use Spy++ and you will see that the message arrives.

Comment: Yes, using Spy+ I see the WM_KILLFOCUS. Looking at the message's properties I see that the CB's parent is the MyDlg window. This is what I expect too. MSDN says the WM_KILLFOCUS message gets sent to the parent which would be the MyDlg. So I am still puzzled as to why my handler isn't catching the S message. I can do a message Find in Spy+, type in the hwnd and it finds the CB object, but I don't see it highlighted in the Spy+ Window object list and I don't see the hwnd I got from the hit when I drag the Finder Tool target over the CB edit box. Why isn't there an hwnd match somewhere?

Comment: To simplify things I made a simple MFC app with a ribbon. I put a combobox on the ribbon. I made a handler for the WM_CREATE message so the CB's edit box would work and I made a handler for the WM_KILLFOCUS message. Leaving the CB's edit box does not send a WM_KILLFOCUS message to its handler. In fact, the handler code seems to have been optimized away (the debug ball is empty). What am I missing? Spy+ says the message is being generated when I leave the CB edit box.

Comment: When I get time, I'll submit the bug and workaround as a bug report.

Comment: Double-check the message map entry from the `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP()..` section. Verify that it's `ON_CBN_KILLFOCUS(IDC_THE_COMBO, &CMyDlg::OnKillfocusMyCombo)`. I've messed that one up before, other macros e.g. `ON_EN_KILLFOCUS` compile fine but don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. This is a bug in MFC. (It's over 4 years later and it is still there.) Somehow `ON_CBN_KILLFOCUS` handler is never called although the Win32 `CBN_KILLFOCUS` notification itself is broadcast.

To fix this override the `WindowProc` for the dialog manually (Win32-way):

```
LRESULT CMyDlg::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

    //Fix for the bug in MFC
    if(message == WM_COMMAND)
    {
        if(HIWORD(wParam) == CBN_KILLFOCUS &&
            LOWORD(wParam) == Your_ComboBox_ID)
        {
            OnCbnKillfocusComboBox();
        }
    }

    return CDialog::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```